# Not showing full model in rendered view and camera view after a certain distance

Tags: rendering, camera

In my view port full model is showing, but in camera view and also in render view the full view of model is not showing.

Comment: You likely need to adjust the clipping range of the camera.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have two different settings for your view port clipping and your rendering camera clipping.

- To check the one in your view port (in Blender 2.8+): press
  <kbd>N</kbd> , select *View* and you have *Clip Start* and *Clip
  End*.
- To check the one used by your camera select the camera object, go to
  green *Object Data Properties* and in the panel *Lens*.

By default, they do not have the same value

[image: default value for clipping camera and viewport]